# refomulation of an optimization problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have written a program for optimizing a set of generators. And I need to reformulate this problem, to include additional generators and constraints.

I have hourly price and cost data and need to figure out when a generator should run or just stay off. I describe the problem in more detail below. The first description is of the current optimization which only deals with a single generator. Following I show a WIP formulation for dealing with multiple generators and an additional demand constraint.

In the first formulation, it is possible to optimize for **income6** using a non linear solver, and then optimize **revenue6** using an integer solver. This is since revenue6 is a monotonic function of income6. Thus x_1 is optimized first, then x_2 and x_3.

## Part 1

**Problem Description 1**

- x_1 is the generator output at any one point in time and is constrained to be between a min and max capacity
- x_2 is an integer variable used simply to turn the generator off completely
- x_3 lastly is another integer variable used to apply a startup cost whenever the generator is switched on.
- x_1, x_2 and x_3 are vectors where the index of the vector (eg. x_1(1:5) is the data for the first 5 hours)

**Objective Function (totrevenue6):**

- efficiency6 = 0.2621*x_1 - 0.1229*x_1^2 + 0.2543
- income6 = {(x_1)*(AC_1 + FC_1 - P_1 + FC_1/{el_efficiency6})}
- revenue6 = - SC_1*x_3 + x_2*(income6)
- **totrevenue6** = -sum(revenue6)

**Constraints:**

- min_capacity <= generator6 power (x_1) <= max_capacity
- 0 <= generator6 toggle (x_2)<= 1
- The startup constraint (x_3) is x_2-x_{2-1}<=x_3
- 0 <= (x_3)<= 1

## Part 2

**New Formulation**

I have continued to develop the program to optimize the set of generators and I now need to add the profit from two additional blocks to the objective function.

**Objective Function (totrevenue):**

```
  income6 = {(x_16)*(AC_1 + FC_1 - P_1 + FC_1/{el_efficiency6})}
  revenue6 = - SC_16*x_36 + x_26*(income6)

  income7 = {(x_17)*(AC_1 + FC_1 - P_1 + FC_1/{el_efficiency7})}
  revenue7 = - SC_17*x_37 + x_27*(income6)

  income8 = {(x_18)*(AC_1 + FC_1 - P_1 + FC_1/{el_efficiency8})}
  revenue8 = - SC_18*x_38 + x_28*(income6)   

  **totrevenue** = -sum(revenue6+revenue7+revenue8)
```

**Constraints**

- x_16 + x_17 + x_18 >= demand at time t
- x_26*x_16 + x_27*x_17 + x_28*x_18 >= demand at time t

Essentially I need to make sure that both optimizations meet the demand for each time step. (x_16 is generator electricity output for block 6, x_17 is for block 7, etc.)

## Question:

Can someone suggest a good way of reformulating this problem such that it can be solved by a linear integer solver? or perhaps first by a non linear solver and then by an integer solver as I have done in the first formulation?

Extra Question:
Will it be possible to optimize the sum of (income6 + income7 + income8) using a non linear solver first, and then optimize totalrevenue using an integer solver, and in this way maintain monotonicity? I would like to maintain monotonicity so that I dont have to use a non linear integer solver.

Many thanks,
Jesse